# How to get date difference from two dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr

I have two datafram as mentioned:

DF_1

```
ID         Date1
1          12/01/2017
2          15/02/2017
3          18/03/2017
```

DF_2

```
ID         Date1
1          05/01/2017
1          15/01/2017
1          18/01/2017
2          10/02/2017
2          13/02/2017
2          15/02/2017
3          22/03/2017
```

I want to calculate the difference between dates for a particular id in DF_1 to same id in DF_2 with most recent old date in DF_2 as compare with date of DF_1.

For Example: For ID=1 the Date of DF_1 is 12-01-2017 and Most recent old date for that in DF_2 would be 05-01-2017 because 15 & 18 both are > than DF_1 Date.

Required Output:

```
ID         Date1       Count
1          12/01/2017   7
2          15/02/2017   0
3          18/03/2017  -4
```

Comment: Why is `Count == 7` for `ID == 1`?

Comment: please be more specific about: `"... with most recent past date in DF_2 as compare ..."`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following reproduces your expected output:

```
library(tidyverse);

df1 <- read.table(text =
    "ID         Date1
1          12/01/2017
2          15/02/2017
3          18/03/2017", header = T) %>%
mutate(Date1 = as.Date(Date1, format = "%d/%m/%Y"));


df2 <- read.table(text =
    "ID         Date1
1          05/01/2017
1          15/01/2017
1          18/01/2017
2          10/02/2017
2          13/02/2017
2          15/02/2017
3          22/03/2017", header = T)  %>%
mutate(Date1 = as.Date(Date1, format = "%d/%m/%Y"));


left_join(df1, df2, by = "ID") %>%
    mutate(Count = Date1.x - Date1.y) %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    slice(ifelse(
        all(Count < 0), 
        which.min(abs(Count)), 
        which.min(Count[Count >= 0]))) %>%
    select(ID, Date1.x, Count)

## A tibble: 3 x 3
## Groups:   ID [3]
#     ID Date1.x    Count
#  <int> <date>     <time>
#1     1 2017-01-12 7
#2     2 2017-02-15 0
#3     3 2017-03-18 -4
```

Explanation: Calculate the time difference between `df1$Date1` and `df2$Date2`, group entries by `ID`, and keep only the row which has the smallest positive time difference, unless all time differences are negative in which case report the smallest absolute time difference.

Comment: I want to Minus Date of DF_1 for that particular ID from Date of Most recent old date which should be `<=` date of DF_1. (For Example For `ID=1` the Date of DF_1 is `12-01-2017` and Most recent old date for that in DF_2 would be `05-01-2017` because 15 & 18 both are `>` than DF_1 Date.

Comment: @Roy1245 This is not clear at all. There is no *"most recent old date"* for `ID == 3`; then why is `Count == -4` in the last row? Shouldn't this entry be `NA` or similar?

Comment: Because for ID=3 there is not date < Date of DF_1 for ID=3.

Comment: @Roy1245 That's exactly my point; so your rule *"most recent old date"* should give an `NA` for `ID==3`, shouldn't it?

Comment: Yes that would be fine.

Comment: @Roy1245 Ok. I've updated my answer to reproduce your expected output. Please take a look. Still not 100% clear on your rules.

Comment: @Mauruts Evers Not working, don't know the final dataframe has 0 rows

Comment: @Roy1245 It's working here, with data and results as given above. Can you double-check? My example is 100% self-contained and reproducible. The only thing I can think of is an issue due to older `tidyverse` libraries on your side. I have `tidyverse_1.2.1` and `dplyr_0.7.4`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your last row is wrong, as for `ID=3` the `df2` value is not before the `df1` value.  Assuming that is correct, you can do this...

```
df3 <- df2 %>% rename(Date2=Date1) %>% 
  left_join(df1) %>% 
  mutate(datediff=as.Date(Date1,format="%d/%m/%Y")-as.Date(Date2,format="%d/%m/%Y")) %>% 
  filter(datediff>=0) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarise(Date1=first(Date1),Count=min(datediff))

df3
     ID Date1      Count 
1     1 12/01/2017 7     
2     2 15/02/2017 0
```